# Time varying effect in time dependent cox model

Tags: r, cox-model, biostatistics, epidemiology

In the case of Stanford heart transplant dataset (jasa), is it possible to check if the effect of the time dependent covariate of transplant is time varying as well ? If that's the case can we compute hazard ratios per time intervals after transplant compared with those who never had?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, yes. The `cox.zph()` function can evaluate the Cox proportional hazards assumption that coefficients are constant over time, and plots of scaled Schoenfeld residuals will show the shape of the estimated coefficient values over time. The `jasa1` data frame has a cleaned version of the data set, from which the model in Section 3.3 of the [time-dependence vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) can be fit.

```
library(survival)
jasaModel <- coxph(Surv(start, stop, event) ~ age*transplant + surgery + year, data= jasa1, ties="breslow")
jasaModel
# Call:
# coxph(formula = Surv(start, stop, event) ~ age * transplant + 
#    surgery + year, data = jasa1, ties = "breslow")
#
#                    coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z      p
# age             0.01527   1.01539  0.01750  0.873 0.3828
# transplant      0.04457   1.04558  0.32171  0.139 0.8898
# surgery        -0.62113   0.53734  0.36786 -1.688 0.0913
# year           -0.13608   0.87278  0.07090 -1.919 0.0550
# age:transplant  0.02703   1.02740  0.02714  0.996 0.3193
#
# Likelihood ratio test=16.06  on 5 df, p=0.006687
# n= 170, number of events= 75
```

In this case, however, there is little evidence that the proportional hazards assumption is inappropriate.

```
cox.zph(jasaModel)
#                 chisq df    p
# age            0.2825  1 0.60
# transplant     0.0431  1 0.84
# surgery        0.1143  1 0.74
# year           2.0098  1 0.16
# age:transplant 2.4099  1 0.12
# GLOBAL         5.7623  5 0.33
```

If you plot the scaled Schoenfeld residuals you can see that there is little time dependence in the estimated coefficient values. For example, for the `age:transplant` interaction:

```
plot(cox.zph(jasaModel)[5])
```

[image: Schoenfeld residuals plot for age:transplant interaction]

That approach will show the estimated time-dependence of coefficient values in situations where there is such a dependence.